# close duplicate tabs in web browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser, tabs

I am trying to open multiple links from excel such as follows

```
https://in.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=NSE:ASHOKLEY2!
https://in.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=NSE:ASIANPAINT2!
https://in.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=NSE:AUROPHARMA2!
https://in.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=NSE:AXISBANK2!
```

what i want to accomplish is, once this tabs are open in browser, if any of this links are again opened by using excel, they should be get automatically closed.

I used `clutter free extension` ,
issue i am facing with it is that, once the first link is opened all other links get automatically closed
i.e if  i open link `https://in.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=NSE:ASHOKLEY2!`
next three links mentioned above dont open at all.
but what i expect is all this links should open, and next time if any of this links are visited again then they should not be opened.

how can i solve this issue?

Comment: @wOxxOm  i added javascript tag , because i wanted to know if it is possible to check using javascript  if  any two tabs have same name and then delete one of them

Comment: If you know JavaScript you can write an extension and use [chrome.tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) to get all tabs titles.

Comment: @wOxxOm   is it possible to close tab if its title match with any other tab?

Comment: Of course. See the link I gave which shows what the API can do.

Comment: ok. i used one another extension "duplicate tab closer" , which has option "compare with title" but it didnt worked as i expected.  time to write my own extension i guess.